# Adding date and time to excel document quickly

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I am making a log and need to keep track of multiple items parsing through different stages. For further statistical analysis I need to have date and time added to each stage for the particular item. It is okay to do it manually but I find using the Ctrl method below tedious:

```
Ctrl+; followed by Space then     Ctrl+:
```

I am using excel M365 version. Any ideas on how to fill these cells simpler than this to minimize time to train others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a macro like this one:

```
Sub DateTime()
   ActiveCell.Value = Now
   ActiveCell.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.